# Is it possible to make subset of warnings as errors

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to preprocess few files using c-preprocessor to expand macros using `-Werror`,  I notice redefined errors while pre-processing.

```
fileA.h:203:0: error: "TEST_DIR" redefined
 #define TEST_DIR      2

fileB.h:119:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define TEST_DIR     90

fileC.h:203:0: error: "TEST_DIR" redefined
#define TEST_DIR_TASK                  1000


 fileD.h:119:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
   #define TEST_DIR_TASK                  8
```

Actually `TEST_DIR_TASK` is defined in hexa-decimal format in one file and in other it is defined in decimal, Both values implies same and i Would like to ignore those. Is there any special gcc flags that helps to ignore some subset of warnings based on some criteria. Thanks!

Comment: `8` in hexa-decimal is `8` in decimal, so that doesn't match the `1000` as seen here (maybe you meant binary?). Also, if any of it is hexa-decimal, where is the `0x` prefix?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how `2` and `90` can represent the same value regardless of what base they are in respectively.

In any event, if you really want to redefine them (seems like a bad idea to me) you could always just undef them first, like:

```
// fileA.h
#undef TEST_DIR
#define TEST_DIR  2

// fileB.h
#undef TEST_DIR
#define TEST_DIR 90
```

Or if they're really equivalent and the first definition is as good as the last you can only define them if not already defined:

```
// fileA.h
#if !defined(TEST_DIR)
# define TEST_DIR 2
#endif

// fileB.h
#if !defined(TEST_DIR)
# define TEST_DIR 90
#endif
```

As I say this seems like a really bad idea and just asking for all sorts of failures in the future, but it should avoid compiler warnings / errors.

Comment: Yeah, Its a bad idea to have such redefines. We actually want to catch up those issues on our existing wide range of code. Was checking if any flags in gcc would help.

Comment: There is not such a flag.  I've given the options you have for avoiding the warning/error.

Answer (score 0):

[GCC appears not to have a switch to disable this specific warning.](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) By default, if GCC has a command-line switch for controlling a specific warning, it is included in the warning message.

With Clang, you can use `-Wno-macro-redefined` to disable warnings for redefining macros. (This also disables errors for this when warnings have been elevated to errors.)

Comment: I could not find `-Wno-macro-redefined` in gcc link which you shared.

Comment: @Naga: As my answer states, GCC does not have this switch. Clang does.

Comment: Okay.. Never heard of Clang.  How does it work ? And how do we set that.

Comment: @Naga: Clang is a different compiler that is largely GCC-compatible. You would need to install it on your system. Information is [here](https://clang.llvm.org).